# How can i place validations for fields in groovy for specific format

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have Domain class and in that for a particular field of type String, it accepts alphanumeric values,i need a validation in the format it should accept only AB12-QW-1 (or) XY-12 values. how can i validate the field.

Please suggest the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assume your domain class looks like this

```
class Foo {
  String bar
}
```

If you can define a regex that matches only the legal values, you can apply the constraint using:

```
class Foo {
  String bar
  constraints = {
    bar(matches:"PUT-YOUR-REGEX-HERE")
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you can easily list all the legal values, you can use:

```
class Foo {
  String bar
  constraints = {
    bar(inList:['AB12-QW-1', 'XY-12'])
  }
}
```

If neither of these solutions will work, then you'll likely need to write a [custom validator method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)

Comment: @tim - thanks for the vote, though I'm not 100% sure that 'AB12-QW-1' and 'XY-12' are literally the only values the field will accept. I assumed they're a reference to some obscure encoding system

Comment: Yeah, but without a better description, I just grabbed the low-hanging fruit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

```
class YourDomain {
  String code

  static constraints = {
    code( validator: {
      if( !( it in [ 'AB12-QW-1', 'XY-12' ] ) ) return ['invalid.code']
    })
  }
}
```

However, your explanation of what codes are valid is a bit vague, so you probably want something else in place of the `in` call

[edit]

Assuming your two strings just showed placeholders for letters or numbers, the following regexp validator *should* work:

```
constraints = {
  code( matches:'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]|[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}' )
}
```

And that will return the error `yourDomain.code.matches.invalid` if it fails

Comment: `inList` seems like a simpler way of doing this, though it does require you to use the conventional grails error message codes

Comment: Yeah, it was just an example of custom validation...probably a bad one (as examples go)

Comment: I think it has some value insofar as it shows how you can use custom error message keys

Comment: thanks. But how can i show the appropriate user friendly message